# QGIS "Execute SQL" does not accept more than 1 input table

Tags: qgis, sql, qgis-processing, virtual-layer

I have some problems using the "Execute SQL" algorithm (in General Vector Tool) in the Processing Toolbox.
No problem when I've got only 1 input table, but when I try to select 2 tables as input data I get an error: **virtual: Referenced table input2 in query not found!**

For background information my SQL expression (works fine with add virtual layers):

```
select makepoint((st_line_locate_point(p.geometry, a.geometry)*st_length(a.geometry)) /*:real*/,"Z" /*:real*/,2154) as geometry
from 'input1' as a, 'input2' as p
```

Comment: I can't find the tool 'execute SQL' anywhere in the Vector menu...

Comment: @DPSSpatial It's in `Toolbox -> GDAL/OGR -> [OGR] Miscellaneous -> Execute SQL`. At least in 2.14 and 2.16 it is.

Comment: when making use of toolbox -> qgis algorithms -> vector general tools -> execute sql then I can select multiple layers and use all of them in the sql-expression

Comment: @PieterB did you use input1 and input2 for calling your first and second entries ? or 'input1' and 'input2' ?

Comment: @sylvain calling layers without quotes just like you do in sql

Comment: @PieterB does not work either ! Do you have a simple example that works ?

Comment: You have to refer to the name of the layer. Not input1, input2, ... eg: select makepoint((st_line_locate_point(p.geometry, a.geometry)*st_length(a.geometry)) /*:real*/,"Z" /*:real*/,2154) as geometry
from layerA as a, layerB as p

Comment: @PieterB It seems to work if I refer to the name of the layer, yes but does not work if I refer to the name of the input. for example point_layer and line_layer (the names of my inputs)

Comment: @PieterB My layers in inputs do not always have the same name, it is the interest of the graphic modeler normally! no?

Comment: I have the same problem in QGIS 2.18.7, for both the toolbox and the  modeler versions of "Execute SQL." I can refer to specific layers by name in the query, or use one parameter layer as input1, but anything more than the single parameter does not work. Did anyone come across a fix or workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is due to a bug in the "ExecuteSQL.py" script, where an index wasn't being incremented (see the bug report [here](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16129)). That bug report says the issue has been resolved, so I'm not sure why it's still happening on my machine but the fix itself was easy enough to do by hand, following the fix shown [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/4079/commits/b91b421d036032c5c4b18b734632c19e1df504f4).

Basically it involves adding the following line to "ExecuteSQL.py" after line 106:

```
        layerIdx += 1
```

I just made the change, tried it and it worked.

Comment: I added the line in ExecuteSQL.py in  QGIS 2.18.28, but an python error appears when loading Qgis `layerIdx += 1 IndentationError: unexpected indent`

Comment: Looks like you don't have the correct number of spaces at the front of your line. This matters because indentation is how Python keeps track of nesting and loops etc.

Comment: so obvious...Thanks. But the issue is before that : in the graphic modeler `ExecuteSQL` can't use a layer previously generated with `points layer from table`. It is a part of a bug that is not fixed so far according to your link (?).

Comment: @Leehan for the Graphical Modeler you might want to look at [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280080/cannot-find-layer-error-with-execute-sql-in-qgis-graphical-modeler). The bug report I referenced was reopened about three months ago, because of problems with the Graphical Modeler. I just tried using ExecuteSQL: it works from the Processing Toolbox, but not within the Graphical Modeler, so maybe these problems require different fixes.