# Cannot find layer error with Execute SQL in QGIS Graphical Modeler

Tags: qgis, sql, qgis-modeler

I'm trying to sort a shapefile by one of its attributes using "Execute SQL", in the QGIS Graphical Modeler.

Using a vector as input is working fine, but when I use a layer generated by an algorithm I have this error message : "virtual: Cannot find layer OUTPUT_shp20180419141642572".

Can someone help me with this ?

To sum-up :
[image: here is my problem]

Comment: As per the [help/on-topic] it is OK to try and reproduce software problems in a Q&A here, but if you think this is a bug then be sure to submit it to the QGIS development team. Please post a link to the bug report here.

Comment: @underdark here is the ticket: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16129#change-95647  It is set as fixed, but the problem still exist in QGIS 3.4.1 and the nightly build version

Comment: What if you change "input1" in your SQL to the id of the Mean algorithm?
So I mean, maybe you should not use the same SQL codes.

Comment: @pnz it's a bug in the algorithm.  See the ticket mensioned above

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue:  [Bug report #16129 Processing : execute sql alg does not work with input2 ... inputN parameters](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16129)

Comment: Is there a substitute tool that works in Graphical modeller?